# Can we mask postman mock server url

Tags: postman, mockserver, postman-mock-api-server

I have mocked my API's using postman mock server
I want to mask the url of mock server
ex : my current url **kj3433434n34kjrh98434kjn.mock.pstmn.io** TO **examplename**  this name i want to mock
i have explored in google but no helpful article found. please help me

Edited :
my current url : **https://kj3433434n34kjrh98434kjn.mock.pstmn.io/test/api**
expecting url  : **https://examplename/test/api**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can create an `environment` variable and add the Mock URL value to `examplename`.

This can then be referenced in the request using the `{{examplename}}` syntax.

[image: Postman]

Comment: no, i have already generated mock url so now i want it to mask with some name "examplename"

Comment: Where are using this new 'exemplename` url? The URL for the mock, is the URL for the mock - resolving that to a new location wouldn't go the correct place.

Comment: the "examplename" is just a mask to the original value "kj3433434n34kjrh98434kjn.mock.pstmn.io"

Comment: but you must be wanting to use that for _something_ or why both masking it?

Comment: i want to give some name to my server to easily understand and differentiate